# languageEmbedding=“always” breaks Experience Editor in Sitecore 9.2

Tags: multilingual

I've got this weird issue with Sitecore 9.2. I'm building a multi-lingual site and require the language code to always appear in URLs. I've configured this on the link provider as follows:

```
<add name="custom" type="custom.Feature.ItemResolver.LinksProvider.CustomLinksProvider, custom.Feature.ItemResolver" 
                     addAspxExtension="false" 
                     alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" 
                     encodeNames="true" 
                     languageEmbedding="asNeeded" 
                     languageLocation="filePath" 
                     lowercaseUrls="true"
                     shortenUrls="true" 
                     useDisplayName="false" 
                     domainlowercaseUrlsPath="true"  
                     patch:before="add[@type='Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
```

With languageEmbedding set to "always", The experience editor fails for all languages other than Global English (the default language for the site). It seems the site resolving does not work, as it appends sc_site=website on the end of the EE URL, which causes it to fail. If I change website to the correct site name, it works.

UPDATE: When I say EE fails, this is what I see:
[image]

All the correct components are on the page, and they have datasources defined, however they don't seem to render anything.

With languageEmbedding set to "asNeeded", Experience Editor works fine, however the link provider is not adding the language code to the URL.

Smells like a Sitecore bug to me.. anyone else experienced this, or found a workaround? I'll be raising a support request with Sitecore about this soon, but figured I'd try here first and save myself some time and frustration.

Thanks heaps :)

Comment: What do you mean by "it falil on EE" ? What is the error you getting?

Comment: Actually it doesn't through an error or anything, it just shows a page with all the shared components but without any data sources rendered. Strangely, if i edit the contents of any of those components, they have data sources and content, however they don't render in EE.  If i change the sc_site querystring to match the site name, it works fine.

Comment: And what happens if you disable your custom LinkProvider, and set `LanguageEmbedding=always` on the default Sitecore LinkProvider?

Comment: That's an excellent idea @jammykam, i'll give that a go shortly.

Comment: Same behaviour with my custom ItemResolver and LinkManager disabled, and languageEmbedding="always" on the site definition.

Without the languageEmbedding="always", it works.

Comment: Same behaviour with languageEmbedding="always" configured on the default Sitecore linkProvider.

Comment: I would raise this with Sitecore Support as a bug, since it doesn't appear to be related to your custom code.

Comment: Thanks, I agree.  I've written a workaround (wasn't too hard to work around this one) and set to asNeeded, as I don't have time to wait for a fix. But will log it nonetheless.